# WAMP: Apache refusing connections outside the network

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp

I have wamp installed. I ran the server, everything is running fine from localhost and my local ip address. I forwarded port 80 on my router. Whenever I try to access the server from the outside, using my real ip, it doesn't work and timeouts.

I though port forwarding is not working, forwarded another port for different service and it went through, so the problem is with apache. I checked the error log, didn't find any errors. Skype is off. Any tips what could be causing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check windows firewall to see if it allows access to port 80? Also, can you try from another machine on the same subnet behind the same router?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your ISP is blocking port `80/tcp`. Try forwarding a high ephemeral port to port 80 on your server.

Comment: Thanks! I running a different server app on port 80 and it went through, so it appears that's not the case. Any other tips?